# .bashrc : how to check in what terminal the shell is running

Tags: bash, shell, emacs

I have the following in my .bashrc:

```
bind '"\e[A"':history-search-backward
bind '"\e[B"':history-search-forward
```

However, when I call `shell` from within Emacs, I get the following message:

> bash: bind: warning: line editing not enabled
>
> bash: bind: warning: line editing not enabled

And as a consequence my prompt gets messed up.

How can I detect (from within my .bashrc), that my shell is being called from emacs or, alternatively, not from a standard terminal?

My goal is to wrap the calls to `bind` so that they are only executed in a proper terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probing for a variable called `EMACS` didn't work for me under Emacs 25 and bash 4.2.

However, looking for differences in the environment of the shell within and outside of Emacs I found a variable called `INSIDE_EMACS` only set when running from Emacs.

The solution that worked for me is therefore:

```
if [[ ! -v INSIDE_EMACS ]]; then
    bind '"\e[A"':history-search-backward
    bind '"\e[B"':history-search-forward
fi
```

Echoing `INSIDE_EMACS` returns the Emacs release number.

Comment: Note that the value of `INSIDE_EMACS` varies depending on the Emacs command which was used.  e.g. `M-x shell` and `M-x term` produce different values.  You can use this to further differentiate between those types (which are, of course, very different to one another).

Answer (score 2):

`bash` disables line editing because when it sees a variable named `EMACS` in its environment. You can use the same variable to conditionally create those bindings:

```
if [[ ! -v EMACS ]]; then
    bind '"\e[A"':history-search-backward
    bind '"\e[B"':history-search-forward
fi
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt answer. Somehow I still get the same warnings when calling the shell from emacs. If I then `echo $EMACS`, I noticed the variable is not assigned. (bash 4.2)

Comment: @dangom I rejected your edit only because I don't know `emacs` very well and just saw the reference to `EMACS` in the `bash` man page. Feel free to post your edit as a new answer if that worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet specifically tests if line editing is enabled in bash or not. It works everywhere, not just in the emacs shell:

```
if [[ "$(set -o | grep 'emacs\|\bvi\b' | cut -f2 | tr '\n' ':')" != 'off:off:' ]]; then
  echo "line editing is on"
fi
```

It could probably be simplified...